# Uploading file when knitting has been complete

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to upload an html file automatically to a ftp server once it has been knitted.

I added this code to my rmd file:

```
RCurl::ftpUpload(here::here("rmd", "final.html"), Sys.getenv("MY_FTP_DETAILS"))
```

Obviously, there is an error since the HTML file hasn´t been created yet.

Do you know of any work-around to get this file uploaded when the knitting process has been finalized?

Comment: Are you using an IDE / Editor , a script or something like "make" to build?

Comment: At the end, I wrote a separate R script that calls the rmarkdown::render step, and then uploads using the command above

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use setwd(FTP server folder path) for the current project, and then have the knitted document saved to the current directory, which is the FTP server...
what do you get if you do

`RCurl::ftpUpload("path/to/file/final.html"), Sys.getenv("MY_FTP_DETAILS"))`